How to calculate percentages based on subtotals in a pivot table in Looker Studio
I have the following table:

I have two fields "is_lead" repetead, but the second one (the percentage variable) is wrong: As you can see, I ran "percent of total" from "comparison calculation" in the last column but that's not what I want... What I'd like to calculate is the row "is_lead" / the sub-total at the end of each level of work_experience (sub total of program_advisor)... I've tried CASE WHEN, all the variants of comparison calcualtions etc...
What can I do to run correctly my second "is_lead" field as % of subtotals? thanks
